# Append elements to a list without the lists library module in Erlang

Tags: list, erlang

I want to append elements to a list and I'm not allowed to use the lists library or any other BIF. An example of how I want it to be:

```
Eshell V5.9.1 (abort with ˆ G)
1> Db = db:new().
[]
2> Db1 = db:write(apple, fruit, Db).
[{apple,fruit}]
3> Db2 = db:write(cucumber, vegetable, Db1).
[{apple,fruit},{cucumber,vegetable}]
```

The code I have now for this (not working):

```
write(Key, Element, []) -> [{Key, Element}|[]];
write(Key, Element, [H|T]) -> [H|write(Key,Element,T)].
```

The error I'm getting is when I do this:

```
3> Db2 = db:write(cucumber, vegetable, Db1).
** exception error: no match of right hand side value [{apple,fruit},{cucumber,vegetable}]
```

I understand the error message but I dont know how to go from here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that this is just a case of `Db2` already having a value, and it's a different value from the return value of `db:write` (which is `[{apple,fruit},{cucumber,vegetable}]` according to the error message).  Type `Db2.` to see what value it has, and type `f(Db2).` to "forget" its value, so that you can assign to it again.

Comment: That fixed it! The problem was not my solution, like you said Db2 already was assigned a value and when restarting the shell, it worked! Thanks legoscia!

Answer (score 2):

You can append element to the list by `List ++ [Element]`

Answer (score 1):

Appending with ++ operator is not very recommended. You should use it only with small lists.

You have two options:
- lists:append (you said it's not an option ) or
- you can put in in front of a list with | operator.